# How to use IN operator with SQLite in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I have add the status column to my database table and I want to search result and display all the names of employee where status is open. When I run the application I'm getting exception `SQliteException no such column xxx` while compiling query.

I can't figure out how to do this.

Here is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_data);

        searchSpinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.searchSpinner);
        btnSearch=(Button)findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
        newLeadDat_List = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_DisplayData);

        displayNewLeadData();
        System.out.println("Data Displayed Succesfully!!!!!!!!!");

        searchSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                selectedSearchItem=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().trim();
                System.out.println("selectedProductItem =" + selectedSearchItem);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            }
        });

        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                dbAdapter=new DataBase_Adapter(Serach_Data.this).open();
                dataBase = dbAdapter.getDatabaseInstance();


                    String query = "SELECT name FROM "+ DataBase_Adapter.TABLE_NEW_LEAD +" where "+ DataBase_Adapter.KEY_NEW_LEAD_STATUS +" IN  ("+ selectedSearchItem + ")";

                    cursor = dataBase.rawQuery(query , null);
                    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(Serach_Data.this, 
                              R.layout.search_data_item_listview, 
                              cursor, 
                              new String[ ] {"name"}, 
                              new int[ ] {R.id.textView2_Name});

                    new_Lead_List_Adapter = new New_Lead_List_Adapter(Serach_Data.this  ,
                                 arrayList_newLead_Name );

                    newLeadDat_List.setAdapter(adapter);    
            }
        });
    }

    public void displayNewLeadData() 
    {
        dbAdapter=new DataBase_Adapter(Serach_Data.this).open();
        dataBase = dbAdapter.getDatabaseInstance();

        Cursor mCursor = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM " + DataBase_Adapter.TABLE_NEW_LEAD, null);

        mCursor.moveToFirst();

        arrayList_newLead_Name.clear();

        {
            do 
            {   
                  arrayList_newLead_Name.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DataBase_Adapter.KEY_NEW_LEAD_NAME)));
            } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
        }

        new_Lead_List_Adapter = new New_Lead_List_Adapter(Serach_Data.this  ,
                                                        arrayList_newLead_Name );
        newLeadDat_List.setAdapter(new_Lead_List_Adapter);
        new_Lead_List_Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mCursor.close();
        System.out.printf("Data will Be Display." , new_Lead_List_Adapter);

    }
}
```

Here is my Log Cat stack trace info.

```
12-13 14:43:37.880: I/System.out(528): selectedProductItem =open
12-13 14:43:39.760: I/Database(528): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such column: open
12-13 14:43:39.760: D/AndroidRuntime(528): Shutting down VM
12-13 14:43:39.760: W/dalvikvm(528): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
12-13 14:43:39.810: E/AndroidRuntime(528): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-13 14:43:39.810: E/AndroidRuntime(528): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: open: , while compiling: SELECT name FROM new_lead where status IN  (open)
12-13 14:43:39.810: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
12-13 14:43:39.810: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
12-13 14:43:39.810: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
12-13 14:43:39.810: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
12-13 14:43:39.810: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
12-13 14:43:39.810: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
12-13 14:43:39.810: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1356)
12-13 14:43:39.810: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1324)
12-13 14:43:39.810: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at com.lead_management_project.Serach_Data$2.onClick(Serach_Data.java:86)
12-13 14:43:39.810: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
12-13 14:43:39.810: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
12-13 14:43:39.810: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-13 14:43:39.810: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-13 14:43:39.810: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-13 14:43:39.810: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-13 14:43:39.810: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-13 14:43:39.810: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-13 14:43:39.810: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-13 14:43:39.810: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-13 14:43:39.810: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: The error shows that you have no such a column did you check the column name?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
" where "+ DataBase_Adapter.KEY_NEW_LEAD_STATUS +" IN  ('"+ selectedSearchItem + "')";
```

I am assuming your column is of some string type.

If you have more than one status which you want to query for, then
you need to loop through your statuses and in this loop you should append 
1) ' 
2) status value (some string like open, closed, etc.) 
3) ' 
4) , (comma) 
to some StringBuilder object, then remove the last , (comma) and then 
produce an IN clause from this StringBuilder object. And make sure you 
produce at least one status because "IN ()" is not valid in SQL.

Comment: Since its a column name ' is not needed!  That may be useful if its a value

Comment: @Peter.petrov Column name is status and selectedSearchItem is the value which is insert in status column.

Comment: @tazeenmulani I don't get what you mean. This is not a valid SQL statement: SELECT name FROM new_lead where status IN  (open). This is quite obvious. What are your possible statuses? Are they strings or ints or ... ?

Comment: @Arju Can you elaborate? What is a column name?

Comment: From and in shows column names not values within a column, So the column name is not represented by 'name' only name is specified

Comment: @Arju Thank you for explaining me what "From and In shows"! I still didn't get much though. But thanks.

Comment: @Arju Column name is status , and "open" is value in status column.I want to display only name's whose status is open.

Comment: @Arju , KEY_NEW_LEAD_STATUS="status" this is column name.

Comment: @ peter.petrov , Yah i try it out but getting different error like = "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist ".But

Comment: @ peter.petrov _id does not exist in my Database.

Comment: @tazeenmulani KEY_NEW_LEAD_STATUS="status" , = ? what that, Can you log the query and post it here

Comment: @peter.petrov , "id" column is exist in my database and i have taken "id" auto increament.

Comment: @Arju ,String query = "SELECT name FROM"+DataBase_Adapter.TABLE_NEW_LEAD +" where "+ DataBase_Adapter.KEY_NEW_LEAD_STATUS +" IN  ("+ selectedSearchItem + ")";

                    cursor = dataBase.rawQuery(query , null);

Comment: You have mistake here "SELECT name FROM". Put a space at the end like this: "SELECT name FROM ".

Comment: Nope what i mean is execute the app and log the string query

Comment: Yeah may be he's right, Log your query before execution, Check the syntax

Comment: @peter.petrov , I want to do like this = SELECT first_name, last_name, subject 
FROM student_details 
WHERE subject IN ('Maths', 'Science'); 

The output would be similar to:

first_name last_name subject
------------- ------------- ----------
Anajali Bhagwat Maths
Shekar Gowda Maths
Rahul Sharma Science
Stephen Fleming Science

Comment: You need to loop through your statuses and append 1) ', 2) status value 3) ' 4) , (comma) to some StringBuilder object, then remove the last , (comma) and then produce an IN clause from all this. And make sure you produce at least one status because "IN ()" is not valid in SQL.

Comment: @peter.petrov , Please help me i m trying since 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

First uninstall the application and run it Again. The database is in emulator or phone is last used one, It is not updated. When you are uninstalling the application the database is also removed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention you added column later, you'll need to change database version.

Comment: down-vote because further questions to clarify the OPs question should be make in the comment are below the OPs question.

Comment: I know, but what can i do, I do not have enough reputation to comment.

Comment: patience, young padawan! =) ps. Removed the down-vote because you know the proper good practice.

Comment: ok. I agree but as said earlier without 50 reputation it is not possible to comment even on authors question. I have reworded comment so it looks more like an answer.